How to use spacing inside columnlayout in qml
In below example you can see I have added two RowLayouts inside ColumnLayout, and also added space of 40. If i run this example in qt design studio then i couldn't see the space between two RowLayouts, Could you please anyone tell me why this is not working?
Rectangle {
    width: 800
    height: 600

    color: Constants.backgroundColor

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 40 //not working, not able to seperate two rowlayouts, Why?

        RowLayout {
            id: rowLayout
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 20
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
            Layout.topMargin: 0

            Button {
                id: button
                text: qsTr("Button")
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }

            Button {
                id: button1
                text: qsTr("Button")
                Layout.preferredWidth: 70
            }

            Button {
                id: button2
                text: qsTr("Button")
                Layout.preferredWidth: 70
            }

            Button {
                id: button3
                text: qsTr("Button")
                Layout.preferredWidth: 70
            }

            Button {
                id: button4
                text: qsTr("Button")
                Layout.preferredWidth: 20
            }
        }

        RowLayout {
            id: rowLayout2
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 20
            anchors.top: rowLayout.bottom
            Layout.fillHeight: false
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop

            Button {
                id: button6
                text: qsTr("Button")
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }

        Item {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
    }
}

Why spacing not working?

When using Layouts:

do not use width, use Layout.preferredWidth instead
do not use height, use Layout.preferredHeight instead
do not use anchors, wherever possible use equivalent Layouts

    Rectangle {
        width: 800
        height: 600
        color: "orange"
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 40
            RowLayout {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 20
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
                Layout.topMargin: 0
                Button { text: qsTr("Button"); Layout.fillWidth: true }
                Button { text: qsTr("Button"); Layout.preferredWidth: 70 }
                Button { text: qsTr("Button"); Layout.preferredWidth: 70 }
                Button { text: qsTr("Button"); Layout.preferredWidth: 70 }
                Button { text: qsTr("Button"); Layout.preferredWidth: 20 }
            }
            RowLayout {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 20
                Layout.fillHeight: false
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
                Button { text: qsTr("Button"); Layout.fillWidth: true }
            }
            Item { Layout.fillHeight: true }
        }
    }

You can Try it Online!
